# Adding items to PopupMenu

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I am trying to find how I can add items to devExpress PopupMenu. I have tried the following:

```
        manager = new BarManager();
        listBoxMenu = new PopupMenu(manager);

        listBoxMenu.ItemLinks.Add(manager.Items["Remove item"]);
        listBoxMenu.ItemLinks.Add(manager.Items["Clear items"]);
```

As shown here `http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5472` (at the bottom), but it gives me an error saying the item is not initialized.

What is the proper way to add items? I can't find it anywhere.

Edit, here is how I did it:

```
        //Creates the popup menu to be used for the keywords listbox
        manager = new BarManager();
        listBoxMenu = new PopupMenu(manager);

        item = new BarButtonItem(manager, "Copy");
        item2 = new BarButtonItem(manager, "Clear Item");
        item3 = new BarButtonItem(manager, "Clear All Items");

        listBoxMenu.ItemLinks.Add(item);
        listBoxMenu.ItemLinks.Add(item2);
        listBoxMenu.ItemLinks.Add(item3);

        //Adds the seperator on the second item
        item2.Links[0].BeginGroup = true;

        manager.ItemClick += manager_ItemClick;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this code snippet and implement using the same way.

//create popup and manage objects

```
private DevExpress.XtraBars.BarManager barManager1;
        private DevExpress.XtraBars.PopupMenu buttonContextMenu;
        DevExpress.XtraBars.BarButtonItem menuButtonExport = new DevExpress.XtraBars.BarButtonItem();
        DevExpress.XtraBars.BarButtonItem menuButtonSave = new DevExpress.XtraBars.BarButtonItem();

        public TestForm8()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            barManager1 = new BarManager();
            this.barManager1.Form = this;
            buttonContextMenu = new DevExpress.XtraBars.PopupMenu(barManager1);                 
            this.buttonContextMenu.Name = "subViewContextMenu";            


            menuButtonExport.Caption = "E&xport";
            menuButtonExport.Id = 1;
            menuButtonExport.Name = "menuButtonExport";
            menuButtonExport.ItemClick += new ItemClickEventHandler(menuButtonExport_ItemClick);

            menuButtonSave.Caption = "S&ave";
            menuButtonSave.Id = 2;
            menuButtonSave.Name = "menuButtonSave";
            menuButtonSave.ItemClick += new ItemClickEventHandler(menuButtonSave_ItemClick);
//add items to barmanager
            this.barManager1.Items.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItem[] {
            menuButtonExport,
            menuButtonSave
            });
//create links between bar items and popup
            buttonContextMenu.ItemLinks.Add(barManager1.Items["menuButtonExport"]);
            buttonContextMenu.ItemLinks.Add(barManager1.Items["menuButtonSave"]);
//finally set the context menu to the control or use the showpopup method on right click of control
            barManager1.SetPopupContextMenu(btnInsert, buttonContextMenu);
}
```

Ref by step to include popup:

[How to: Create a popup menu](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5474)
[How to: Add items to a container bar item (menu)](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5412)
[Populating Popup Menus](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5472)
[BarManager.SetPopupContextMenu Method](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsBarManager_SetPopupContextMenutopic)

Comment: Thanks, very good. Something I would change is to not handle each button's itemClick event but handle the click event for the manager and add the functions there.

Answer (score 1):

Your manager is empty:

```
manager = new BarManager();
```

The example you linked to is using a `BarManager` that was already created: `barManager1`, which I assume was created in the designer and populated with items.

From their [BarManager help page](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1083):

> After a BarManager has been added to a form/user control, you can create bars and bar commands using context menus right on the form, using the bar manager's Customization Window or its Designer. Please see the Toolbars Customization section, to learn more.

Comment: I added my code to the question, can you review if I did it in the correct way please?